# How to use EXT-GWT ComboBox

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How do I use ComboBox in [EXT-GWT](http://extjs.com/products/gxt/) with static data.
For example I just want to hard code (for demo purposes) list of First Names and display it to the user.
I don't want to use any dummy objects that they are using in their samples. Where can I find simple example with Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I use in my project:

```
SimpleComboBox combo = new SimpleComboBox();
combo.add("One");
combo.add("Two");
combo.add("Three");
combo.setSimpleValue("Two");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maksim,

I am not sure whether it helps you or not.  It was based on the [GWT-EXT](http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/) for combobox. 
As I remember that, it wraps the String[] with SimpleStore object.

```
//create a Store using local array data  
 final Store store = new SimpleStore(new String[]{"abbr", "state", "nick"}, getStates());  
 store.load();  

 final ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();  
 cb.setForceSelection(true);  
 cb.setMinChars(1);  
 cb.setFieldLabel("State");  
 cb.setStore(store);  
 cb.setDisplayField("state");  
 cb.setMode(ComboBox.LOCAL);  
 cb.setTriggerAction(ComboBox.ALL);  
 cb.setEmptyText("Enter state");  
 cb.setLoadingText("Searching...");  
 cb.setTypeAhead(true);  
 cb.setSelectOnFocus(true);  
 cb.setWidth(200);
```

I hope it helps. 
Tiger

ps) Did you try this example ?

```
    // create store 
ListStore<String> store = new ListStore<String>(); 
store.add( Arrays.asList( new String[]{"A","B","C"})); 
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox(); 
cb.setStore(store);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is something is wrong with SimpleStore object. It does not exist. I think it is no longer exist in this library.

Comment: I believe that the ComboBox in Ext-GWT API has setStore(ListStore) function to load data. so we can use as below:(It might be the same as the demo example )

// create store
ListStore<String> store = new ListStore<String>();
store.add( Arrays.asList( new String[]{"A","B","C"}));

ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.setStore(store);


I hope it helps.

Comment: Now it complains about String in "ListStore<String>", here is error "Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <M extends ModelData> of the type ListStore<M>"