# GXT (Ext GWT) problem with SimpleComboBox

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

When creating a GXT SimpleComboBox (as in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161796/how-to-use-ext-gwt-combobox/1167547#1167547)),

```
    final FormPanel fp = new FormPanel();

    SimpleComboBox<String> combo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
    combo.add("One");
    combo.add("Two");
    combo.add("Three");
    combo.setSimpleValue("Two"); // I'd like to preselect that value

    fp.add(combo);
    RootPanel.get().add(fp);
```

my combo box only contains the value "Two". The values "One" and "Three" are completely removed from the combo box. This doesn't happen, when I delete the line `combo.setSimpleValue("Two");`

I'm using GXT 2.2.3 and GWT 2.2.0 (tested on Linux/Firefox and Linux/Chrome). Is this a bug / did it work in older versions of GXT/GWT, or am I doing something wrong?

## Update

I accepted an answer, and it solves the problem: Add the line

```
combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
```

But I'm still looking for an explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried visiting here ? [SimpleComboBox Problem in GWT](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?89994-SimpleComboBox-problem-with-GXT-2.1.0-and-GWT-2.0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The linked forum thread did help to solve the problem (insert `combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);`), but it *didn't help me to understand*, why I need to do this, or why the old behavior was wrong. Why would `setSimpleValue` remove the other values? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, but that's what it does. I've experienced this problem as well.

Answer (score 8):

I guess this is caused by the filtering feature of the combobox. This works by checking the string input and tries to match it with the values in its store - then only displays those items it thinks are relevant to the string input.

Since you made "two" the default value it thinks someone wrote "two" in there and tries to help you by showing only those values that you could think of while typing "two".

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `combo.setForceSelection(true);`